# how to add class in 4th li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am fun of `Jquery` but I have only basic knowledge. can somebody guide me how to add `class` in my 4th `li` using jquery.

```
<ul id="items">
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in Advance .... hope this make sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#items li").eq(3).addClass("your-class");
```

More info: [eq API](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zucqL/)

Comment: `#items > li` would be better imho, or `#items > li:nth-child(4)` for that extra oomph.

Comment: For his sample, `#items li` is enough. Also, `nth-child` doesn't work with chaining, it is better to use `eq`.

Comment: @Jack there are some edge cases where any selectors after pseudo-selectors won't work.

Comment: But those edge cases don't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

use nth-child() selector

try this

```
ul#items li:nth-child(4)
{
color: #000;
}
```

Comment: jhunlio is asking for jQuery solution not for css

Comment: nth-child is not supported by IE8

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#items li:nth-child(4)" ).addClass("your-className");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/6V6Hw/)**